# Is there a word to describe beliefs that are neither scientific nor false nor religious?

Tags: word-choice

If I believe that the Spaghetti Monster lives under my bed, what word would you use to describe this? It can not be proven that the Spaghetti Monster does not live under my bed because you have not looked there but I also have not proven it to be true myself. It's not a religious belief because religious beliefs are by definition "the belief in and worship of a superhuman controlling power, especially a personal God or gods" and this is not a belief in a higher power, just a scary Spaghetti Monster. And it's also not a scientific belief because it has not been scientifically proven. Furthermore, it is not a false belief because one has not proved it to be false.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Fairy tales? All you mention is true for elves, unicorns, dwarves and the like. It's also true for [Russell's teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_teapot).

Comment: It seems to me that your claim about a spaghetti monster living under your bed *is* false. Or at least unprovenbutsoridiculouslyunlikelythatnobodywouldinvestthetimetocheck. (Is that a word?) As such, this seems to be more a question about the philosophical nature of truth and falsehood than about the English language.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your long but obviously correct word broke my phone's page so I can't read parts of your comment lol. But let's say the belief is un-spaghettimonsterrelated. Maybe I believe that somewhere out there in the world, there exists someone who looks identical to myself. I can't prove it true or false unless I look at every single person in the world. But it isn't a belief that is [word you used].

Comment: @EFrog Oops. The comment was "It seems to me that your claim about a spaghetti monster living under your bed is false. Or at least unproven but so ridiculously unlikely that nobody would invest the time to check. (Is that a word?) As such, this seems to be more a question about the philosophical nature of truth and falsehood than about the English language."

Comment: *Religious*, despite your claim otherwise, unless you can show how it covers religions like Buddhism that don't have such a belief. If it's excessive from the viewpoint of your professed religious beliefs, then *superstitious*.

Comment: I know it's false because he lives under MY bed.

Comment: The question is incorrect because there is no logic in it. If belief can be proven, then, I think, it is knowledge, but not belief. I really don't understand what OP means by scientific belief. Belief by definition is something we take on trust  without evidence or proving. If we rely on evidence then it is not belief anymore, we call that knowledge.

Comment: How is it possible that belief can be false? Belief can seem false to one opponent. Another opponent will say that it is substantiated and not false at all.  And there is no evidence at all, that's why it is belief.

Comment: @Humbulani A belief is "an acceptance that a statement is true or that something exists" I can accept that a statement is true without it actually being true. Also I didn't just say evidence, I said scientific evidence (i.e. evidence that a majority of people will not argue against)

Comment: @Isaiah Turner The point is that there is no clear answer to your question, because this is an 'opinion based' question. The answers are not based on facts, but on what people think of your beliefs. I would say that your statements about Spaghetti Monster are  substantiated, because I happened to see such a monster under by bed too. Another answerer would say that these are unsubstantiated claims or superstitious beliefs because they are ridiculous on their humble opinion. No-one knows the truth or can prove it. The answerers expressed their personal or biased opinion about your belief.

Comment: As I said, your question was formulated incorrectly. :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "scientific belief", the entire point of science is it's based on proving something is correct, not just believing it's correct.  An unproven assumption is called a hypothesis, a proven one a theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not a religious belief because religious beliefs are by definition "the belief in and worship of a superhuman controlling power, especially a personal God or gods" and this is not a belief in a higher power, just a scary Spaghetti Monster. And it's also not a scientific belief because it has not been scientifically proven. Furthermore, it is not a false belief because one has not proved it to be false.

If it has been neither proved true nor proved false , then it would be:

- an unsubstantiated belief

Here's the definition from Oxford Dictionaries online:

> Definition of *unsubstantiated* in English:
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> > Not supported or proven by evidence:
> >
> > > - 'unsubstantiated claims'

**Reference**: "unsubstantiated", Adjective. Oxford Dictionaries Online. Accessed January 6th 2015

Comment: This is the closest answer I can find to correct. I wish there was a word with a slight variation in definition. Specifically "Not supported or proven by scientific evidence" as many would accept things like the Bible as evidence although not technically scientific.

Comment: Araucaria? John? [Have you come back?](http://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/2013/nov/26/araucaria-john-graham)

Comment: Oh, if only he had ... I'm really glad you recognise my namesake hero! Most people think I'm a girl because of my 'name'! Ggrrr :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is interesting and it can be interpreted in at least two ways.

If we focus on your phrase, "It can not be proven...", then I think the concept you are searching for is [falsifiability](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Falsifiability.html).

Alternatively, if we focus on the phrase, "...I also have not proven it to be true myself," then I believe the concept you are looking for is willful ignorance because you refuse to investigate your "belief".

Comment: Popperism (the inability to be falsified) is a synonym in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Beliefs can be many things: moral, philosophical, existential... An all-encompassing term would simply be *personal beliefs*.

Answer (score 1):

A **notion** is a fanciful or foolish idea ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/notion)). A spaghetti monster under the bed is just a notion, with no facts to prove or disprove it.

> an idea that is believed to be true or valid without positive knowledge (*has this naive notion that most people are basically honest*) ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/notion))

Other words that indicate a belief not supported by evidence include

- feeling
- sense
- hunch
- instinct
- intuition

but these words tend to convey an increasing degree of reliability, which may be based on experience in similar circumstances where the belief was ultimately proved.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bertrand Russell's Theory of Descriptions (Kripke in *Naming and Necessity* took a different view), "The Spaghetti Monster lives under my bed", when correctly analysed, is a combination of three propositions:
1. There is a Spaghetti Monster.
2. At most one thing is a Spaghetti Monster.
3. Everything that is a Spaghetti Monster lives under my bed.

My strong suspicion is that the first of these propositions is false, with the result that your belief itself is also false. The fact that it may not yet have been *proved* to be false is irrelevant to its truth status.

Comment: The classic example (where France is a Republic) is: "The King of France is bald."

Comment: It is my suspicion that, if there is one spaghetti monster, there must be many spaghetti monsters (the species would have died out otherwise). Therefore, either (1) or (2) is false.

Comment: Unless there were many and there now remains only one: vide Martha the passenger pigeon, or indeed the Loch Ness Monster.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding  Isaiah Turner's question: "If I believe that the Spaghetti Monster lives under my bed, what word would you use to describe this?" 
Belief is a term notorious for its lack of apt synonyms, so, intead of looking for alternative words, I think it's better to look for words that may qualify a belief. In the case of the Spaghetti Monster under the bed I'd qualify that belief as **implausible**.

As Humbulani points out in Comment 4, it makes little sense to qualify a belief as true or false. All assertions of the form: *I believe that...* must be taken at true ones (even if the person is lying, since we cannot prove she doesn't believe in that). On the other hand beliefs may be plausible or implausible, according to whether they are considered by the audience as reasonable, credible or conceivable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logical argument for this not being scientific is based on false assumptions. You could consider this a scientific belief. Science allows and even encourages beliefs that are suspected but have not yet been proven or disproven and refer to them as *hypotheses* or a *[hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis)*. If you are looking for an adjective to describe this you could say **hypothetical**.